# How to make a structure as a parameter to a function/method?

Tags: c#

Can I make the clstableclass dynamic or an object like

```
TableDependency.SqlClient.SqlTableDependency<clsTableClass> tbl =
    new SqlTableDependency<clsTableClass>(sConnection, sTable);
```

where obj is a structure

```
public clsTableUpdate(object sender, string sConnection, string sTable, obj  )
{
    try
    {
        TableDependency.SqlClient.SqlTableDependency<obj > tbl =
            new SqlTableDependency<obj >(sConnection, sTable);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorOccur(sender, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency/blob/master/TableDependency.SqlClient/SqlTableDependency.cs SqlTableDependency can accept only types which are class as T. So you can not use structure type here

Comment: See [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)